# Network Servers Block missing in "Add blocks interface"

Tags: moodle

We are using mnet to connect our server (Client) to another moodle instance (server).

All the configuration for moodle has been completed and we double checked that we did not miss any.

Our "client" does not show the "Network Servers Block" in the Add Blocks Interface.

Any assistance is welcomed.

Thanks,
Chandrashekar Singh

Answer (score 0):

Check the client has the capability `block/mnet_hosts:addinstance`

go to site admin -> users -> permissions -> check system permissions

select the client username

filter for `block/mnet_hosts:addinstance`

is it allowed?

If not then check the roles for the client. By default, the capability is assigned to roles `editingteacher` and `manager`, as well as an admin users.

Comment: I tried all of the options described here before and after the response was given. I do not, however have a solution. Every other installation I've tried worked well with showing the Network Servers block except our main moodle site.